# Pyomo model: Error when I call the simulator

Tags: python, pyomo

I'm trying to solve the Trambouze reactions using Pyomo, I defined the Pyomo model as:

```
#kinetic constants
k1 = 0.0001 #mol/dm3*s
k2 = 0.0015 #s-1
k3 = 0.008 #dm3/mol*s

#create pyomo model

def PFR_trambouze(CAo = 0.112, CBo = 0.132, CXo = 0.0783, CYo = 0.0786):

  
  m = ConcreteModel()

  #def time variable and bounds
  m.t = ContinuousSet(bounds=(0.0, 300.0))
  #def species concentrations
  m.CA = Var(m.t)
  m.CB = Var(m.t)
  m.CX = Var(m.t)
  m.CY = Var(m.t)

  #def diferential variables
  m.dCA = DerivativeVar(m.CA)
  m.dCB = DerivativeVar(m.CB)
  m.dCX = DerivativeVar(m.CX)
  m.dCY = DerivativeVar(m.CY)

  #initial conditions
  m.CA[0.0].fix(CAo)
  m.CB[0.0].fix(CBo)
  m.CX[0.0].fix(CXo)
  m.CY[0.0].fix(CYo)

  #differential equations
  @m.Constraint(m.t)
  def ode_A(m, t):
    return m.dCA[t] == - k1 - k2*m.CA[t] - k3*m.CA[t]**2

  @m.Constraint(m.t)
  def ode_B(m, t):
    return m.dCB[t] == k1*m.CA[t]
  
  @m.Constraint(m.t)
  def ode_X(m, t):
    return m.dCX[t] == k1
  
  @m.Constraint(m.t)
  def ode_Y(m, t):
    return m.dCY[t] == k3*m.CA[t]**2
  

  return m
```

To solve the model, I call the Simulator function, pass the pyomo model and choose the package and then defined the number of points:

```
sim = Simulator(PFR_trambouze(), package = 'scipy')
tsim, profile = sim.simulate(numpoints= 100)
```

When I run the code,  I receive the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-00475f40d0ce> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 sim = Simulator(PFR_trambouze(), package = 'scipy')
----> 2 tsim, profile = sim.simulate(numpoints= 100)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyomo/dae/simulator.py in simulate(self, numpoints, tstep, integrator, varying_inputs, initcon, integrator_options)
    921                     "The scipy module is not available. Cannot simulate the model."
    922                 )
--> 923             tsim, profile = self._simulate_with_scipy(
    924                 initcon, tsim, switchpts, varying_inputs, integrator, integrator_options
    925             )

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyomo/dae/simulator.py in _simulate_with_scipy(self, initcon, tsim, switchpts, varying_inputs, integrator, integrator_options)
    957                         p.set_value(varying_inputs[v][tsim[i - 1]])
    958 
--> 959             profilestep = scipyint.integrate(tsim[i])
    960             profile = np.vstack([profile, profilestep])
    961             i += 1

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_ode.py in integrate(self, t, step, relax)
    429 
    430         try:
--> 431             self._y, self.t = mth(self.f, self.jac or (lambda: None),
    432                                   self._y, self.t, t,
    433                                   self.f_params, self.jac_params)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_ode.py in run(self, f, jac, y0, t0, t1, f_params, jac_params)
   1342         args = [f, y0, t0, t1] + self.call_args[:-1] + \
   1343                [jac, self.call_args[-1], f_params, 0, jac_params]
-> 1344         y1, t, istate = self.runner(*args)
   1345         self.istate = istate
   1346         if istate < 0:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyomo/dae/simulator.py in _rhsfun(t, x)
    655 
    656                 for d in derivlist:
--> 657                     residual.append(rhsdict[d]())
    658 
    659                 return residual

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

I can't find the cause of the error and I checked my pyomo model several times and compared it with some examples and I didn't see anything wrong.

What's the cause and how can the problem be solved?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `rhsdict`?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand. Could you explain?

Comment: in this line `for d in derivlist:  residual.append(rhsdict[d]())`